# Modify the interval of axis label in Plot

Tags: plotting

I am new to Mathematica and I want to do a very simple modification to my plot.  I want to modify the interval of the axis label. This the plot by Mathematica.
[image]
This is what I want.
[image]

Below is my code.

```
Plot[Evaluate[
Module[{tL = 303.15}, {1 - tL/i, 1 - Sqrt[tL/i]}], {i, 500, 1500}], 
Frame -> True, AxesOrigin -> {500, 0}, 
PlotRange -> {{500, 1500}, {0, 1}}]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Module[{tL = 303.15}, 
  Transpose@
   Table[{{i, 1 - tL/i}, {i, 1 - Sqrt[tL/i]}}, {i, 500, 1500, 100}]], 
 Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Range[500, 1500, 100], Range[0, 0.9, 0.1]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
    None}, {Table[{i, i}, {i, 500, 1500, 100}], None}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{500, 1500}, {0, 0.9}}]
```

[image]